# Cosa sono le "prese per innaffiare"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> Il giardiniere ci lasciò: aveva il cappello di paglia con il nastro grigio sporco, il grembiule turchino legato dietro il collo e alle reni; uscì dalla serra con la gomma da applicarsi alle **prese per innaffiare**. Noi ci sedemmo nel vano di una delle vetrate della serra.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa sono queste "prese per innaffiare"? Ho cercato il termine "presa" in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tantissime accezioni che si trovano, non riesco a capire a quale corrispondano quelle che appaiono nel testo.

Comment: Prese d’acqua, impropriamente rubinetti.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le prese per innaffiare non sono altro che particolari rubinetti che si trovano sulle tubazioni di sistemi di irrigazione professionali.

Nel caso delle serre o giardini particolarmente grandi vengono distesi tubi che hanno queste prese posizionate ad una distanza regolare, in modo da poter collegare un tubo e così irrigare dove necessario.

Immagina, analogamente, l’impianto elettrico di un grande ufficio in cui i cavi distesi sotto al pavimento hanno in corrispondenza delle scrivanie le prese elettriche.

Comment: Una cosa così credo http://hr.selfitalia.it/documents/tutorial/img/img_consigli_utili/scheda-39-57.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Come precisa il  dizionario [Hoepli](http://10%20TECN%20Apertura,%20nel%20punto%20di%20derivazione,%20di%20una%20conduttura%20di%20liquidi%20o%20gas:%20p.%20del%20gas%20%7C%7C%20estens.%20Rubinetto,%20valvola%20o%20altro%20dispositivo%20di%20regolazione%20del%20flusso%20di%20una%20conduttura), “presa” in senso lato può essere usata per riferirsi a un dispositivo (rubinetto, valvola etc.) per l’erogazione di liquidi o gas:

***Presa:***

> (10)  TECN)  Apertura, nel punto di derivazione, di una conduttura di liquidi o gas: presa del gas.
>
> - (estensione)  Rubinetto, valvola o altro dispositivo di regolazione del flusso di una conduttura.

[image]

Nel brano citato le prese dell’acqua per annaffiare possono essere dei semplici rubinetti o altri dispositivi collegati al sistema idrico della serra.

[image]